# Using Remmina to connect to a remote host

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-access, remmina

I utilize the RDP protocol by using the Remmina software in order to connect to a remote host. If I close the Remmina session utilizing the disconnect option, will the remote host continue its operation?

Answer (score 0):

Usually host will continue to operate normally.

But it depends on host logon settings / scripts.

From my practice - Windows applications keep running and I find them in their places on next RDP login.